# how to use json_query filter to extract all items equals to a value

Tags: ansible, json-query

Here is my json output:

```json
{
    "kind": [
        {
            "inventory": "",
            "inventory_sources": "",
            "job_templates": "",
            "workflow_job_templates": "104"
        },
        {
            "inventory": "",
            "inventory_sources": "",
            "job_templates": "114",
            "workflow_job_templates": ""
        },
        {
            "inventory": "24",
            "inventory_sources": "",
            "job_templates": "",
            "workflow_job_templates": ""
        },
        {
            "inventory": "",
            "inventory_sources": "108",
            "job_templates": "",
            "workflow_job_templates": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to display all items name that contain a specific value. For example, for a search value of `104` I want to get the key name `workflow_job_templates`

I tested some syntaxes without any success:

```yaml
    - debug: 
      msg: "104 is {{kind|json_query(query)}}"
      vars:
        query: "[?*==`104`].workflow_job_templates"
```

I know it is wrong but can someone tell me how he'd do for himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>(Update)</sup>

The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ kind|
                            map('dict2items')|
                            map('json_query', query)|
                            flatten }}"
      loop: [104, 114, 108, 24]
      vars:
        query: "[?to_string(value) == to_string('{{ item }}')].key"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 104 ['workflow_job_templates']
  msg: 114 ['job_templates']
  msg: 108 ['inventory_sources']
  msg: 24 ['inventory']
```

---

<sup>(For the record. Brute-force approach)</sup>

Create a unique list of the keys

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_keys: "{{ my_keys|default([]) + item.keys()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ kind }}"
    - set_fact:
        my_keys: "{{ my_keys|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_keys:
  - inventory
  - inventory_sources
  - job_templates
  - workflow_job_templates
```

Create a dictionary with all values

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict|default({})|combine({item: values}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
      vars:
        query: "[].{{ item }}"
        values: "{{ kind|json_query(query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict:
    inventory:
    - ''
    - ''
    - '24'
    - ''
    inventory_sources:
    - ''
    - ''
    - ''
    - '108'
    job_templates:
    - ''
    - '114'
    - ''
    - ''
    workflow_job_templates:
    - '104'
    - ''
    - ''
    - ''
```

Then search the dictionary. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }} {{ my_dict|dict2items|json_query(query) }}"
      loop: [104, 114, 108, 24]
      vars:
        query: "[?value[?contains(@, '{{ item }}')]].key"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 104 ['workflow_job_templates']
  msg: 114 ['job_templates']
  msg: 108 ['inventory_sources']
  msg: 24 ['inventory']
```

Comment: can you share a tuto link about json_query syntax, I've searched a while about "contains" or other semantics word without probant success

Comment: See [Built-n Functions](https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/specification.html#contains).

Answer (score 3):

`json_query` could be part of the equation for your solution but is really not needed here.

Explanation of the below piece of code:

- Apply the `dict2items` filter to each element of your list. This transforms each mapping to a list of `{key: "key", value: "value"}` pairs
- Flatten the given list so we get all those elements to a single top level
- Select elements having a value of '104' only
- Extract the `key` attribute of each element in a list
- Make that list unique and sort it.

```yaml
    - name: Display all element having a value of 104
      debug:
        msg: "{{ kind | map('dict2items') | flatten
          | selectattr('value', '==', '104')
          | map(attribute='key') | unique | sort }}"
```

Please note that this solution will give you a result if the same key name has different values but one of them is `104. With your above data the result is:

```
TASK [Display all element having a value of 104] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "workflow_job_templates"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct alternative of selectattr with json_query is:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ kind | map('dict2items') | flatten | json_query(query)}}"
      vars:
        - query: "[?value == `\"104\"`].key"
```